# Is it possible to create a .exe with cx_freeze from a py script that need cx_oracle

Tags: cx-freeze, cx-oracle

I have 2 scripts and both are very similar. 
The only difference between those 2 is that script #2 need to connect to an Oracle DB to extract information.
I'm able to create a .exe file and run it with script #1.
But when I try to create the .exe with the script #2 that contains the cx_Oracle library, a window open an close immediately without been able to see the error message.
So my question is... Is it possible to create a .exe if the py script needs the cx_Oracle library?
Fred Lavoie

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I build the .exe file for both scripts with this command ...python.exe setup_usrn-psswd.py build

Comment: When asking technical questions, try to avoid saying "it's not working". What isn't working? Do you see an error message? Does your program lock up? There's a million ways for something to not work.

Comment: Sorry... When I execute my .exe, it should open a window to ask for some paramaters but it shut down immediately and I can't see there's any error messages, it closes too fast.

Comment: @FredLavoie You should [edit] the info from your comments into the question itself.

Comment: I have the same problem. I managed to get a picture of the error and the problem is that it can't find the instant client for oracle (the one you have to add to your variable path). I don't know how to solve it yet